# eclipse server problem from Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat6, tomcat

If i start my Apache server via startup.bat (bin folder), and i issue http://localhost:8080, i got that "cat", and i see successfully the main page.
But in Eclipse IDE, i defined the server on the Servers tab, and i tried to start it within Eclipse. It shows that the server is "started", but when i issue http://localhost:8080, i got that HTTP Status 404 -

```
type Status report

message /

description The requested resource (/) is not available.
```

My question is.. why? why if i start the server manually via startup.bat it display's the startup page of Apache server and if i start within Eclipse i got that error? I should mention that i didn't added any projects for deploying on that server (in Eclipse).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't see the welcome page because eclipse creates another copy of tomcat in your workspace and deploy your project into that installation. Eclipse will only deploy what is inside of your selected project so if you don't add any project to the server in eclipse, the deployment directory for that installation will be empty and will give you a 404 Not found error.

Answer (score 0):

just double click on

**1**.`Tomcat v7.0` Server at `localhost.server`.

**2**. At Server Location select second option.

**3**. Use Tomcat Installation and start the server again :)